# Improving the speed of MySQL query that joins three tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following query which is performing really badly on my hosted server and I wanted to know if anyone has suggestions about how I might improve it.

```
SELECT SUM(IF(rConfirmed = 'Y' and YEAR(rDate) > 2020 and lepgroup = 'B', cbcsightings.count, 0)) as totButterflies,
       SUM(IF(rConfirmed = 'Y' and YEAR(rDate) > 2020 and lepgroup = 'M', cbcsightings.count, 0)) as totMoths,
       SUM(IF(rConfirmed = 'Y' and YEAR(rDate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) and lepgroup = 'B', cbcsightings.count, 0)) as ThisYearButterflies,
       SUM(IF(rConfirmed = 'Y' and YEAR(rDate) > 2020 and YEAR(rDate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) and lepgroup = 'M', cbcsightings.count, 0)) as ThisYearMoths
FROM cbcsightings 
LEFT JOIN cbcspecies ON latin_name = cbcsightings.species
LEFT JOIN cbcrecords ON cbcrec_id = rID
```

There are three tables involved:
cbcrecords (8700 records containing columns that describe the date, location, recorder of butterfly/moth sightings) - rConfirmed and rDate are columns in this table
cbcsightings (c. 25000 records with columns that describe the species sighted on cbcrecords rows) - many to one relationship with cbcrecords - species and count are columns in this table
cbcspecies (480 records with columns that define the individual butterfly/moth species) - lepgroup is a column in this table that defines B for Butterfly and M for Moth - there is a many to one relationship between cbcsightings and cbcspecies

So the point of the SELECT query is to return the total number of butterflies seen this year and in all years, and the total number of moths seen this year and in all years. My intention is that it will select all cbcsightings rows, join to cbcrecords to check the record is confirmed and the date fits the criteria, and join to cbcspecies to determine butterfly or moth.

Am I doing this right? Have I created an inefficient query. Is there a better way of doing what I want to achieve.

If I drop the reference to the cbcspecies table and the column lepgroup then I get results (not the ones I want) in a tiny fraction of a second.

---

Here are my edits in response to comments received:

Here is one of the separated queries:

`enter code here`SELECT SUM(cbcsightings.count) as totButterflies
`enter code here`FROM cbcsightings LEFT JOIN cbcrecords ON cbcrec_id = rID
`enter code here`LEFT JOIN cbcspecies ON latin_name = cbcsightings.species
`enter code here`WHERE YEAR(rDate) > 2020 and rConfirmed = 'Y' AND lepgroup='B'

The first time I tested this in phpMyAdmin in the control panel of the hosted server it took over 2 seconds to run but when I ran it again it took 0.0002 seconds. So I applied this to the home page script for all four queries and tested that in development and live. It was taking around 10 seconds for the home page to display even if I refreshed the page. There are other SQL queries but it was clearly these queries that were causing the delay because I have now added a workaround. The workaround is to add another column to cbcsightings for lepgroup so that there is no need to do the join. This resulted in a dramatically quicker homepage display.

Clearly this is not an elegant solution. I would much rather have a relational database structure but for now I am going to keep those changes in live.

There are a few oddities that I need to investigate. One of them is that my website in development is faster than live regardless of the version of the queries I am using even though I am running it on an old laptop.

Comment: Make sure all the columns used in `ON` conditions have indexes. Other than that, there's probably not much you can do to speed it up.

Comment: really need to see execution plans and timings to know where the holdups are.  It may faster to issue seperate queries using where clause conditions opposed to the if statement and union teh results. (provided the columns used for filters are indexed)   As it stands the if statement has to be evaluated for every record, if instead some critieria were moved to where clause limits  and use multiple queries...   For example move the lepgroup to a where clause and issue two queries and union the data summing there may be faster since it does't have to check for the lepgroup on every record.

Comment: I cannot rewrite this query because I can't really tell to which table most of the columns belong. I can see that you tried hard to squeeze 4 queries into one, that might not be the best strategy. Could you either give the table creations, with indexes, or tell to which table each column you used belongs?

Comment: also why not use rconfirmed = Y in the where clause since it's on every if statement. and remove it from the if.  Depending on how many records this would exclude, you might see a gain.  Simply put the evaluations on the if statements must be done for every record individually.  The more you can move to the where clause the more efficient the query could be; but this could lead to multiple queries combined using union and sum the results after.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your replies. I have adopted your recommendations about moving conditional tests to the WHERE clause and separated the queries instead of compounding them. So I now have four separate queries each just using SUM and the column name. I will show you those in a separate comment shortly

Comment: Please revise the query to qualify each column with the table name or a short alias.

Comment: If you really mean `LEFT`, then what happens in those expressions when a `NULL` is presented due to the row being missing?

Comment: Please provide` SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables - it sounds like some obvious indexes are missing.

Comment: Please reread your question and the comments, and then try to edit your question again. Make it short, and review it before publishing it. Let me put it another way: Why should we put in effort to help you, if you don't read the comments and don't care about what your question looks like?